# What factors would impact an instance of chrome rendering the same content differently from two different origins

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm looking to identify where to start trouble shooting this quirk I've encountered.

I'm using the same tab of the same instance of chrome and loading the same page from the same infrastructure from two different origins.

Origin one is a node server running on localhost.  It produces this rendering:
[image]

Origin two is a remote node server running what I believe to be exactly the same codebase.  It produces this rendering:
[image]

It's almost as if there's a separate media query being called, and that could make sense except that the only MQs I'm using are on sizing and I've reviewed both renderings in property inspector and they line up.

I haven't yet tested in other browsers but I will be doing so shortly.

Outside of MQs, what factors should one be aware of in debugging this sort of rendering issue?

Comment: This is far too abstract. It refers to “same infrastructure” and “same codebase”, or something *believed* to be the same. Are the HTML documents and other files (CSS, JavaScript, etc.) exactly the same, or are they not? If they are, how do the HTTP headers differ?

Comment: Take a look on the magnifier icon in your address bar on first image. You just have magnification enabled for this site. It's just scaled up.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, the only reason I hesitate to say "exactly the same" is because I serve from an opaque server (a PaaS which can only be invoked from a CLI).  The files are ported to the server and I believe are exactly the same.

However,  your question about headers is exactly the sort of directionality I was looking for, if it wasn't for PawełPsztyć's observation.

Comment: @PawełPsztyć, great eye.  Thank you.  I hadn't realized Chrome associated magnification with the URL.  Thanks for this.